# Material-UI TextField errorText not appearing when I set state with Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm validating a login form and dynamically displaying errors, passed as props from the child component. When I set my errors object using Object.assign, the errorText does not appear below the field. If I use setState(), the errorText will display, but the errors object in state does not get updated with all the errors. I believe this has to do with the async nature of setState().

login_page.js (parent component)

```
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            login: {
                userName: "",
                password: ""
            },
            errors: {}
        };
    }

    loginFormIsValid() {
        var formIsValid = true;
        this.setState({
            errors: {}
        });

        if (this.state.login.password === "") {
            Object.assign(this.state, {
                errors: Object.assign(this.state.errors, {password: "Password is required"})
            });
            formIsValid = false;
        }

        if (this.state.login.userName === "") {
            Object.assign(this.state, {
                errors: Object.assign(this.state.errors, {userName: "Username is required"})
            });
            formIsValid = false;
        }

        return formIsValid;
    }
```

login_form.js (child component)

```
<form
    <TextField
        name="userName"
        errorText={this.props.errors.userName} />
    <br />
    <TextField
        name="password"
        errorText={this.props.errors.password} />
    <br />
    <RaisedButton
        label="Log in"
        type="submit" />
</form>
```

I am a React / Material-UI newb so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setState to change states (not Object.assign). So when you are updating state. Also, the usage for Object.assign is

```
Object.assign(newObject, ...objectsToCopyFrom)
```

which will look like

```
var newErrors = Object.assign(this.state.errors, {password: "Password is required"});
```

Then use setState to set the new properties, just replacing what has changed.

```
this.setState({ errors: newErrors });
```

Comment: Sorry, been working in redux all day and misunderstood slightly. I updated my answer: use setState to update the state of your component.